# WordPress Shortcode custom attributes

Tags: wordpress, plugins, attributes, shortcode

I have this shortcode [my_shortcode], how I can add an attribute and retrive it based on the value?
example: [my_shortcode = "website"] or [my_shortcode = "landingpage"]

```
function my_shortcode_add(){
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script-1');
    wp_enqueue_style('my-css'); 
    ob_start();
    include("include/shortcode.php");
    return ob_get_clean();
  }
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_add');
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with this:

```
function my_shortcode_add($atts){
    wp_enqueue_script('my-script-1');
    wp_enqueue_style('my-css'); 
    ob_start();
    include("include/shortcode.php");
    if($atts['website'] == '1'){
       echo 'website work';
    }
    if($atts['landingpage'] == '1'){
       echo 'landingpage work';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
  }
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_add');
```

With this, you can use attribute in shortcode

```
[my_shortcode website=1]
[my_shortcode website=0 landingpage=1]
[my_shortcode landingpage=1]
```

Comment: Works perfect, but I need to call >  if($atts['website'] == '1'  in my included page >  include("include/shortcode.php"); 
Tried but doesn't work.

Comment: I try, and work perfect with new file include/shortcode.php .. check if path file is correct, and send me code of include/shortcode.php

Comment: my include file is a simple <form> but I need to insert attribute result like a hidden input into my form, instead with this code result is printed above or after my form. I sould be create two different include with two different form, but I'd like a best clean solution, without duplicated.

Comment: <form>
 <?php if($atts['website'] == 1){ ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="inputHidden" value="website">
 <?php } ?>
</form> for me work....... you can use php html in your include without problem. Use only $atts